# Fullcalendar: checkboxes on the days of the month

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar 2.0 to display availability of a user. The user can select when they're available and the information will then be stored into the database.

I've edited fullcalendar.js to display a checkbox on every day of the month, and once the save button is clicked all checked days will be stored.

```
        return '' +
        '<td class="' + classes.join(' ') + '" data-date="' + date.format() + '">' + '<input type="checkbox" name="cal[]" id="checkbox-2-' + date.format() + '" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="' + date.format() +'" /><label for="checkbox-2-' + date.format() + '">' + date.date() + '</label>'
            +
        '</td>';
},
```

However when the next or prev button is pressed everything is unchecked. IS there a way to keep the checkboxes checked when the user navigates months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not recomended to alter the content of fullcalendar.js
You should use dayRender method if you want to change the way that td is displayed:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {

            cell.append('<input type="checkbox"............../>');

    }
```

To repoulate checkboxes after month changed you should use an array to store each checkbox checked and then using checkbox changed event pop/push them from that array.

Comment: I've also prepared a small example http://jsfiddle.net/z2t9otxf/ it's just for demo purposes and it can be optimized.